# AngularJS Filtering by an arbitrary number of filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search box that takes a series of terms, separated by spaces, that are split into an array using `string.split(' ')`. Is there a way to apply an arbitrary and potentially large number of filters from that array?

Comment: So the array would define which filters are applied? Could you try to provide a bit more detail? Perhaps an example of what you're trying to get working? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If I have a search query of "john jacob california", I'd want to split that string into an array containing "john", "jacob", and "california". I want to make each of those items in the array be a filter. But I'm not guaranteed to have only three terms each time, potentially there could be any number of terms and I want to be able to support that. I've defined ten filters that the split fills up, but it's not as dynamic or scalable as I'd like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Thad, but actually creating a custom filter module rather than cluttering up the controller. This is how it has worked for me:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<li ng-repeat="object in objects | filterFunction:query"> {{object.state}}

.filter('filterFunction', function() {

  return function (objects, query) {

    // objects is the array being filtered
    // query is the value you passed in

    array = query.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++) {
      // filter the crap out of these objects
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is where you will need to use a predicate function filter instead of a string filter...

like this  (pseudocode):

```
<!--html-->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="object in objects | filter:filterFunction">
        {{object.description}}
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- controller -->
$scope.objects = [ your data here ];

$scope.filterFunction = function(searchVal) {
    // write code that returns true or false depending
    // on whether or not after you split searchVal any 
    // of the elements are in your data
}
```

I haven't tried this, but this is how the documentation says to do it.

-Thad

Answer (score 0):

great multi-filter here:
https://gist.github.com/i8ramin/5825377

Angular JS filter that behaves much like the built in filter one, but allows you to filter with multiple values, space separated. For example "big orange round"